# How can we play youtube video on default mediaplayer of android in phonegap project

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

using a plugin i can play all videos (except from youtube) on default media player. but youtube videos playing only in android youtube application.

```
 private void playVideo(String url) throws IOException {
    // Create URI
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);

    Intent intent = null;
    // Check to see if someone is trying to play a YouTube page.
    if (url.contains(YOU_TUBE)) {
        // If we don't do it this way you don't have the option for youtube
        uri = Uri.parse("vnd.youtube:" + uri.getQueryParameter("v"));
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    } else if(url.contains(ASSETS)) {
        // get file path in assets folder
        String filepath = url.replace(ASSETS, "");
        // get actual filename from path as command to write to internal storage doesn't like folders
        String filename = filepath.substring(filepath.lastIndexOf("/")+1, filepath.length());

        // Don't copy the file if it already exists
        File fp = new File(this.cordova.getActivity().getFilesDir() + "/" + filename);
        if (!fp.exists()) {
            this.copy(filepath, filename);
        }

        // change uri to be to the new file in internal storage
        uri = Uri.parse("file://" + this.cordova.getActivity().getFilesDir() + "/" + filename);

        // Display video player
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "video/*");
    } else {
        // Display video player
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "video/*");
    }

    this.cordova.getActivity().startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: you can't do what you want to do. YouTube video's need to be played with the YouTube app.

Comment: no we can play the youtube video on android media player, i will share the code

Comment: user1585241 ,You did not shared the code yet. i agree with @SimonMacDonald.You tube videos can't be played in android media player.